# Facing issue while processing the POMs when I am cleaning and building the project using maven

Tags: java, jersey

I am using jdk 1.8 and facing the issue while cleaning the package using maven. First, I tried with latest version of jdk but it was having some conflicts w.r.t my test case file. Because, I was able to build it when commenting out the testcases and If I uncomment those testcases, then I was facing the same issue. Now, my team was using the older version of jdk 1.8, so now when I am trying with that I am facing the issue for cleaning the package also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
        <maven.versions.plugin>2.8.1</maven.versions.plugin>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>XYZ-dal-mysql</module>
        <module>XYZ-dal</module>
        <module>XYZ-api</module>
        <module>XYZ-api-dist</module>
        <module>XYZ-api-model</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.versions.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.61</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>XYZ-repo</id>
        <name>XYZ-repo</name>
        <url>XYZ-URL</url>
      </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

The error looks like this :-
(xyz-repo is a private link which needs credentials to download the dependency and I am generating a token so that It can pass the authentication using that token and download)

```
PS C:\Users\DELLUSER\xyz > mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from XYZ-Repo
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: software.amazon.awssdk:bom:pom:2.5.61 (absent): Could not transfer artifact software.amazon.awssdk:bom
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: pom.xml mentioned here is your parent-pom inherited by your project? if this is the parent pom.xml and please share your project pom.xml too. If there is a single pom then please move AWS dependency to dependencies and remove dependencyManagement and change scope to runtime.

Comment: what do you mean by: "my team was using the older version of jdk 1.8"?

Comment: Rerun that with the `-e` flag.  You need to figure out why the `software.amazon.awssdk:bom:pom:2.5.61` artifact dependency is not being downloaded.